# lost private key for MEW . how can i move my tokens from Etherscan

Tags: ether, wallets, tokens, synchronization

Lost private key for MEW. How can I move my tokens from Etherscan to another wallet or exchange?

Comment: Your private key essentially _is_ your account/wallet, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make any transactions without your private key. Unfortunately, your tokens are stuck in your MEW unless you find your private key.